# Any simple abelian group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm looking through a proof that any simple abelian group G is cyclic. The argument goes as follows:

> Suppose G is simple and abelian. Hence, the only subgroups of G are
>   $\{1\}$ and G itself. For $a\neq1\in G$, ${1}< \langle a\rangle\unlhd 
> G$ so $G = \langle a\rangle$ is cyclic.

How do we know that $\langle a\rangle\unlhd 
G$?

Comment: Because any subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: @Jose27 But how do we know that it's even a subgroup?

Comment: If you take the set of all integer powers of some group element, this set always becomes a subgroup - that is the definition of $\lvert a \rvert$.

Comment: Because that's how it's defined; as the subgroup generated by $a$.

Comment: Yes remember that groups need closure under the operation. So something like $a * a = a^2$ needs to be in the group, but now so does $a^2 * a = a^3$ and so on (clearly $a^{\text{ord}(a)} = e$ and we start all over from there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group that is generated by a single element $a\in G$ is a **cyclic** subgroup of $G$.

**Abelian** group's subgroups are all normal. A **simple** group is a nontrivial group whose only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself. So if $G$ is a simple abelian group, then only subgroups of G are {1} and G itself.

Becausa $a\neq 1$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ is the whole group $G$. So G is cyclic.